# How do i send enum string values to client

Tags: c#

I have defined an enum as following.

```
public enum Month
{
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
}
```

I am getting and sending it back to client.

```
public List<Month> GetMonths()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Month)).Cast<Month>().ToList();
}
```

However, I am receiving `0,1,2,3,....11 values` at client end instead of actual string values i.e. month names.

How i can send actual month name as values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GetNames method on Enum:

```
public string[] GetMonths()
{
    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Month));
}
```

Comment: You're not converting it to list? why?

Comment: Well, you are not saying what is your client, but seems like you are serializing to JSON later, for JSON there is no List everythin is an array so you don't need to convert it. If you want you can do a ToList and return a List<string>

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft.Json.Converters provides StringEnumConverter.

Usage:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public Enum SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get list of string.

using Enum static method method [GeNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
List<string> monthsName =Enum.GetNames(typeof(Month)).ToList();
```

Comment: Dont you require to cast it to Month i..e return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Month)).Cast<Month>().ToList();

Comment: @simbada: why do I need to cast . It will correctly return `List<string>`. I have tested It.

Comment: My mistale u dont need to since you are doing List<string>